# clipboard not working when connecting via rdesktop to xrdp-sesman

Tags: debian, vnc, remote-desktop, rdesktop

I have a Debian machine with `xrdp-sesman` setup following way

```
Xvnc           127.0.0.1:5910
xrdp-sesman    127.0.0.1:3350
xrdp             0.0.0.0:3389
```

I am connecting to this machine with `rdesktop` from another Debian machine.

Everything works great, except `clipboard` (i.e. using <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> to copy and paste). When I connect from my Debian machine to a windows machine using the same `rdesktop` client, the `clipboard` works OK.

I suspect that the reason why `clipboard` does not work when connecting to `sesman` is that it is using `rdp` over `vnc` (or something like that). I don't understand how `sesman` works, I have just reused config I have found somewhere.

This is my `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`:

```
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=low
channel_code=1

[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

**How can I make clipboard work when connecting to xrdp-sesman with rdesktop client?**

Comment: Have you tried starting rdesktop with `-r clipboard:CLIPBOARD`?

Comment: @kirill-a - using `-r clipboard:CLIPBOARD` makes no difference. Besides, when connecting to windows machine, clipboard works even without this option.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that there are two clipboard buffers (the Ctrl-C/Ctrl-X/Ctrl-V one, and the middle-click one), and the FreeRDP package (used by Krdc) only notices the first one.

What's worse, the terminal emulator I'm using (Terminator, but it's using the Gnome Terminal widget) requires me to use Shift-Ctrl-C to copy something into the relevant buffer.

It may be that xrdp-sesman is similarly constrained by the limits of the RDP protocol.  See if the Ctrl-C/Ctrl-X/Ctrl-V clipboard is the one that works.

Apologies for not having a completely definitive answer, but hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running vncconfig? one of the things it does is copy the clipboard.

Comment: Why I try to run the vncconfig, the session just disconnected, it is the problem stated in this page: https://www.systemajik.com/blog/remote-desktops-with-vnc-and-rdp/, not sure how to solve this.

Comment: That link appears to be to a tutorial. Perhaps you want to ask a new question.

Comment: Hi, hildred, thanks for the reply, the issue is stated in a xrdp's issue system, I just add some comments recently, see: [copying to the X clipboard causes disconnect from tightvnc · Issue #141 · neutrinolabs/xrdp](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/141)

Answer (score -2):

Try use option `-r` clipboard: `PRIMARYCLIPBOARD`

On some systems is need to check both.